# It is possible to change the splash image with a swf file?

Tags: appcelerator, splash-screen, appcelerator-titanium

that is the question: It is possible to change the splash image with a swf file in Appcelerator?

Answer (score 1):

If by swf you mean Shockwave file, then no, it cannot be done. It can be either PNG image (or Launch File for iOS)

Comment: Thanks for answer. A customer of mine ask me for a splash screen with some images in movement, any clue?

Comment: The launch image or the splash displayed by the Appcelerator framework cannot be animated, it has to be a static image. But that does not stop you from creating your own splash screen. Once the application is loaded it will call index.js (alloy). Inside there you can always create an array of images to create an animation. You can also keep the launcher image and the first image of the splash same, this way, the user will not understand the transition from launcher to splash and it would seem to be a animated splash.

Comment: I got it, I am with classic mode, it is possible to do something like that on it?

Comment: Sure. It is also doable in classic mode too. I think the index.js for alloy is app.js for classic mode. In here, you can create an imageview to show an array of images and once the animation is completed, you can remove the view and move to the next application js file. If this answers your question, request you to mark it so that other can also benefit from it.

Comment: `controllers/index.js` for Alloy is not what `app.js` is for classic. In Alloy this is `alloy.js`. But index *is* the first controller, so this is indeed where you could emulate an animated splash image. Make sure that you do not do anything else in `alloy.js` or before calling `$.index.open()` in `index.js` so that the real splash image is dismissed asap.

Comment: As a side-note; this is not possible directly in Obj-C or Java either. All you can do is use a black splash image and then open a view that emulates a splash screen asap.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Fokke-Appcelerator. index.js is indeed the first controller (entry point) and alloy.js is the first js to be executed.